# differentiate single click and draw on imageview

Tags: android, android-imageview, android-image

**Requirement :**

I want to display popup  if user do single click on image like below,

[image]

If user touches  means I should allow him to draw something on that image like below one

[image]

**What is happening Now :** Sometimes,Instead of getting Popup,It is allowing me to draw on imageview if i do single Click.

**Expected one :**

1]. I want to display popup up if user do Single click on imageview..

2]. Should allow user to draw on selected image if he touch and move on imageview,

Any help??

**Code Snippet**

//To create dialog

```
String [] options  = new String [] {"Take From camera", "Choose From Gallery"};
ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String> (getActivity(), android.R.layout.select_dialog_item,options);
AlertDialog.Builder b  = new AlertDialog.Builder(getActivity());
b.setTitle("Select Image");
AlertDialog d = b.create();
```

//For handing click and touch event

```
imageview.setOnTouchListener(new OnTouchListener() {
    @Override
    public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent e) {

    int action = e.getAction();

        switch (action) {
        case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:

            Log.i("ACTION_DOWN","ACTION_DOWN") ;
          x1 = e.getX();
          y1 = e.getY();

          break;
        case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE:

            Log.i("ACTION_MOVE","ACTION_MOVE") ;

          x2 = e.getX();
          y2 = e.getY();
         onDraw();

          imageview.invalidate();
          x1 = x2;
          y1 = y2;

          break;

        case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:

            Log.i("ACTION_UP","ACTION_UP") ;

            d.show();

          break;
        case MotionEvent.ACTION_CANCEL:

            Log.i("ACTION_CANCEL","ACTION_CANCEL") ;

          break;
        default:
          break;
        }
        return true;    
    }
});
```

//Code to draw something on imageview

```
public void onDraw(){
        if(thePic!=null){
         Bitmap   bmp = Bitmap.createBitmap(imageview.getWidth(), imageview.getHeight(), Config.ARGB_8888);
           Canvas  c = new Canvas(bmp);
            imageview.draw(c);
            Paint pnt = new Paint();
            pnt.setStrokeWidth((float) 4);
            pnt.setColor(Color.GREEN);
            c.drawLine(x1, y1, x2, y2, pnt);
            imageview.setImageBitmap(bmp);
            }

        }
```

Comment: Use OnTouchListener for drawing accordingly to the motionEvent, and OnClickListener for onclick event.

Comment: use this http://developer.android.com/training/gestures/detector.html

Comment: @ Rod_Algonquin I posted my code ,plz check

Answer (score 0):

There's really two ways to differentiate here-  time and distance.  Time means seeing how long it takes between a DOWN and an UP event.  A tap should be fairly quick.  A draw should take more time.  By saving the time that the user touches down and seeing how long it takes for an up, you can decide if you should process moves as drawing or as noise/jitter of the finger.

The other is distance. Your finger will move a few pixels accidentally any time you touch-  its hard to keep exactly still and touchscreens aren't 100% accurate.  What you can do is not draw until the finger has moved some minimum distance-  say 15 pixels-  and only count it as a draw after that occurs.

Basically you can use one or both of these to decide what mode you're in, and react to future touch events in different ways by looking at that mode.  I usually like to use distance because its easier to code-  if you use time and the user moved their finger significantly before the timer is up, you either lose data or you have to store it for use when you finally decide what type of touch it is.

Comment: Thanks for your replay..Could you tell me how to find distance and also time?

Comment: Time-  its in the motion event.  Save the time of the down in a class variable and compare to the time of the event you're processing now.  DIstance-  same thing.  Save the x and y of the down event, and compare to the current one.  As soon as you get over the minimal distance, set yourself to drawing mode rather than click mode.